# What is the binary to decimal conversion of something with 9 bits?

Tags: bit

A byte has 8 bits. Does the 9th bit represent 2^9 = 512? Or does it start over at 2^0 = 1?

What would the decimal conversion of a binary like 101100101 be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

512. Or maybe it's a flag for negatives or maybe a parity bit. Maybe it's even a extra 1 to allow numbers 0-256.

Bits don't mean anything in and of themselves, they only mean what the person who originated the data say that they mean.